# amazon payment service property setup

Tags: amazon-web-services

propertiesCollection = OffAmazonPaymentsServicePropertyCollection.getInstance();

is there anyone know the confidential information of Amazon payment service must be defined in the app.config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the app.config in the OffAmazonPaymentsService.Sample project found at https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/180-8561648-7433252?ie=UTF8&group=offamazonpayments&section=offamazonpayments&version=latest